# How to redirect per-CPU top output to file?

Tags: io-redirection, top

I want redirect `top` output to a file, but I am interested in the per-CPU usage.

Doing just

```
#I only want to see processes belonging to myuser
top -b -d 1 -u myuser > top.txt
```

gives me stats with all the CPUs usage combined.

Running just `top` and then pressing `1` makes top break out per-CPU usage. How do I redirect this to the file?

I've seen some related questions:

[How can I receive top-like CPU statistics from the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27076/how-can-i-receive-top-like-cpu-statistics-from-the-shell)

[How to stream top snapshot into file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/how-do-i-stream-a-top-snapshot-into-a-file)

But not found the answer to how to make the part of the command before the redirect operator take the `1` that top needs for per-CPU stats.

Comment: Have you tried `mpstat -P all` ? This gives similar output to the CPU section in to.

Comment: That works for me too! Thanks! Just of curiosity though, is there some way to do what I asked? There could be situations in future where one wants to redirect a program's output but needs to give it some input after running it but before needing to redirect.

Comment: Great! I'm looking into `top`, but so far didn't no luck.

Comment: There are actually several various implementations of `top`. Which are you using? You can typically find out with `top -v`.

Comment: Use batch mode as described   is this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60328/how-to-stream-top-snapshot-into-file?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for sometime into `top` and there is no straight forward way to do this. As I mentioned earlier, you can use `mpstat -P all > top.txt` and then run your `top` command appending `>>` to output file for per user (you can use `grep` to filter... but that's a different topic :-). 
Can you elaborate what exactly the output you want to see (and is it part of an input for another script)?

Most likely you can use `expect` script to do that (interactively send `1` to `top` and capture the input), but I think it's an overkill.

Comment: I ended up using mpstat 1 -P all > top.txt. I'm trying to graph CPU usage to see how my app performs under high loads and whether it spreads the load across all CPUs evenly. The output data needs heavy massaging to have any spreadsheet program accept it though

Comment: @Jayraj let me know if i can be of further help.